# Is it safe to do multiple Ajax requests to the same file?

Tags: php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a folder with many PHP scripts. And I have let's say a "controller" PHP script.

```
<?php
    $option = $_GET["option"];
    if($option == "show_tables")
        include 'show_tables.php';
    if($option == "change_table")
        include 'change_table.php';
    if($option == "show_ticket")
        include 'show_tickets.php'
    ...
```

I have a 20 options. So my questions is. Is it safe to do multiple AJAX requests to the same file at the same time like:

```
sendAjax("change_table");
sendAjax("show_table");
sendAjax("show_ticket");
...
```

Thanks.

Comment: Yes it should be. Each request will cause a new instance of your one script to be instantiated on the server. Each instantiation will be unique and unrelated in any way.

Comment: That was fast. Thanks

Comment: If I rememeber correctly, you may need to be careful in the javascript making sure you get the right response back from the right call to the server.

Comment: Well remembered. I'll take that in consideration. Thanks again